# Ошибка PLS-00905: object is invalid при вызове функции

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть некая функция на PL/SQL, и есть входной параметр:

```
create or replace function p_m_transport(p_import_log_id in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  answ varchar2(2000);
  item_arr num_arr;
  vc_arr varchar2(2000);
  numberRow number;
  BEGIN
    item_arr := num_arr();
    BEGIN
      item_arr:= str2table(p_import_log_id, ' ');
      FOR i IN 1..item_arr.COUNT LOOP
        item_arr.EXTEND(1);
        item_arr(i): = to_number(vc_arr(i));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINES(item_arr);
      END LOOP;
    END;
    BEGIN
      SELECT id
      INTO   answ
      FROM   dbad_src.m_transport
      WHERE IMPORT_LOG_ID in (item_arr);
    END;
    return answ;
END p_m_transport;
```

Саму функцию вызываю таким вот образом:

```
declare
 v_result number;
begin
  v_result := dbad_src.p_m_transport('21 13 4');
  dbms_output.put_line(v_result);
end;
```

Входной параметр от 1 до 6, из за этого сделал его тип `in number`

Компилятор ругается на:

```
Error(10,7): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(10,19): PLS-00905: object DBAD_SRC.STR2TABLE is invalid
Error(11,7): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(11,26): PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'VC_ARR'
Error(18,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(21,31): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: несовместимые типы данных: ожидается NUMBER, получено DBAD_SRC.NUM_ARR
```

Comment: А как вы проверяете что компиляция прошла и объект валидный ? потому как `item_arr number;` это просто число и к нему вы применяете метод extend который работает с коллекциями, а тип вы не объявляете. Это значит, что функция с таким текстом полюбому должна скомпилится с ошибками (о которых при компиляции сообщено не будет) и будет иметь статус инвалидной.  И `to_number` ни при каких условиях набор чисел из строки в массив не превратит, а вызовет ошибку "Неверное число" при попытке обработки строки содержащей что то помимо цифр

Comment: тут я застрял функция проходить компиляция а при вызове ругается и тут я затрял

Comment: Да, и `select ... into` обязан вернуть одну и только одну строку. Если он вдруг выберет несколько строк по условию `in()` - будет ошибка

Comment: это не важно сама функция выглядит по другому я хочу научиться передовать не сколько параметром сразу

Comment: Но вы в тексте вопроса пишите "результата нет. как исправить". Как можно исправлять не ту процедуру которую вы на самом деле делаете. Если та что вы приводите даже не может нормально скомпилится. Неужели у вас `SELECT NAME, TYPE, line, text FROM user_errors;` дает 0 строк ...

Comment: и когда "ругается" текст или хотя бы номер ошибки (ORA-NNNNN) привели бы ...

Comment: видите ли когда я вопрос задал функция выгладила иначе и тогда не ругалась щас он пишет что str2table не видит эту функцию

Comment: PLS-00905; ORA-06550; а у компилятора : напишу в вопросе

Comment: Я не знаю в оракле функции str2table. Встроенной функции с этим именем не существует. гугл дает примеры подобных функций. например http://www.sql.ru/forum/492220/razbienie-stroki-na-massiv думаю надо просто интегрировать то что она делает в свою функцию

Comment: Вижу вы пытались создавать str2table, но сообщение `object DBAD_SRC.STR2TABLE is invalid` говорит о  том что функция не скомпилилась. так что смотрите user_errors там должны быть ошибки из за которых она не скомпилилась

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция не скомпилировалась. В SQL*Plus посмотрите ошибки компиляции так:

```
SQL> alter function DBAD_SRC.STR2TABLE compile;
SQL> show errors
```